# How to select multiple rows as single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In `sql server`, if I have a table like this :

```
id   |    name
-------------
1    |     x
2    |     y
3    |     z
```

I want to create a stored procedure to return the result in one row
like this :

```
x | y | z
```

my code is :

```
alter PROCEDURE getSupervisorEvaluationPercentages
(
    @FirstSupervisorNumber nvarchar(6),
    @Year int
)
as
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @OptionID INT
DECLARE @getOptionID CURSOR

declare @OptionCountTb table(c int)


SET @getOptionID = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id FROM ObjectiveOption
OPEN @getOptionID
FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getOptionID INTO @OptionID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        select @Count = (select COUNT(Id) from EvaluationProcess 
            where FirstSupervisorNumber = @FirstSupervisorNumber and Year = @Year and FirstSupervisorEvaluation = @OptionID)
        insert into @OptionCountTb values(@Count)
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getOptionID INTO @OptionID
    END
CLOSE @getOptionID
DEALLOCATE @getOptionID
```

I want to display the values of the table `@OptionCountTb` as single row

Comment: check this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830139/converting-rows-to-columns-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

PIVOT is one of the ways
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10840/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    name + ' '
from TableName
for xml path('')
```

Comment: but I want each value to appear as a separate cell

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int,name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO t1
VALUES(1,'x'),
(2,'y'),
(3,'z')

SELECT STUFF((select '|'+name from t1 for XML path('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [name] 
                    from t01
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
 set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [name]
                from t01
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count([name])
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p where 1=2 '
print(@query)
execute(@query)
```